# How to save images stored in assets to Firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am trying to figure out the best way to save an image (png) that is stored in my assets folder to my firebase database so I can retrieve that image/path for later use. Essentially this is what I want:

```
// savedPath was stored and then retrieved from database
let savedPath = '../assets/images/example.png'
return (<Image source={require(savedPath)} />)
```

However, if I just save the path as a string, I can not insert it into the image source like this and it throws an error. I am wondering what my alternative option is to achieve that same thing as the example above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase storage bucket https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ to store all your assets

Then you can store the file name/path in your database and access it from there.

Comment: But how do you take the image from assets and upload it to storage?